# Запомнить позицию чтения QFile

Tags: c++, qt

Есть сторонний лог-файл. При запуске программы необходимо считать с него новую информацию, появившуюся за время, пока программа не работала. Далее в оперативном режиме работаем с появляющимися данными. Перед закрытием необходимо запомнить место, на котором остановились (текущий конец файла по факту), чтобы во время следующего запуска с него начать чтение появившийся данных.
С последнем пунктом проблемы. Не нашла никакой информации по поводу того, как запомнить текущее место чтения даже в пределах одной сессии.
С файлом работаю с помощью QFile. Знаю, что сохранять данные между сессиями можно с помощью QSettings, однако не уверена, что в данном случае это поможет.

Comment: QSettings хороший вариант в данном случае

Comment: Сохранить размер файла лога в байтах перед завершением вашей программы, затем  после её запуска открыть файл и произвести смещение на этот размер (QFile::seek), и продолжить читать?

Comment: @magrif, небезопасно получается с точки зрения того, что файл могли удалить/очистить и наполнить до размера, большего, чем был при закрытии программы

Comment: @magrif, если с удалением и созданием нового файла справится QFileInfo, то с очисткой как быть - неясно

Comment: Очистка/удаление в заданный период?

Comment: @magrif, я имею в виду как незапланированное случайное удаление/чистка, так и плановое, но о котором моя программа ничего не знает

Comment: так лучше регламент очистки сделать, пусть раз в сутки, и отслеживать отметку времени/даты с отметкой при закрытии программы. И если отметка за предыдущий день, то считывать с начала

Comment: @magrif, к сожалению, у меня нет возможности повлиять на файл, так как он не мой, соответственно регламент очистки я также задать не могу

Comment: Тогда поставить задачу тем, кто ответственный? Или если это стороннее ПО, лучше указать в вопросе, какое именно.

Comment: если файл небольшой, то можно банально сохранять копию при закрытии программы, а при запуске сравнивать начальные строки... а можно считать контрольную сумму заданного объёма...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранять время последней считанной строчки лог файла. При повторном считывании искать данное время. Если нету времени у строчек, то лог файл какой-то неправильный.

- Если первая строчка содержит более новое время, чем сохранненное, то значит, что лог файл новый и с ним надо работать с самого начала.
- Если же время в первой строчке более старое, чем мы сохранили, то ищем строчку с сохранненным временем и продолжаем далее работу с лог файлом.

Могут быть нюансы со строчками содержащими одинаковое время. Этот момент нужно проработать. Например, можно сохранить текст строчки.